# How to display Google Maps as basemap in a Silverlight application?

Tags: arcgis-server, google-maps, silverlight

I am writing a web mapping application and I use ArcGIS Server services. I want the application to use Google Maps as a base map. I am new to this job. I have searched a lot on the Internet. But I could not find anything useful. Is there anyone who could help me in this matter. Sample site are shown below.

http://esup.qom.ir

Comment: See also [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-api/sGH1dwVUbf0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in other answer, using google's map tile directly violates their TOS. If you are not married to Silverlight, you can approach this from a different angle and overlay arcgis services onto a google map instead of inserting a google basemap into an arcgis map.

This walks through the basic steps:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/gmaps/help/google_start.htm#topics/gmaps_addmap.html

You still need to be compliant with google's TOS, but you have much greater flexibility when you build on top of google's gmap.

Answer (score 1):

Google licensing terms generally prohibit accessing their tile service from outside of the controls they provide.

Answer (score 0):

How about using **Add Data from GIS Online** which is provided by ESRI, it will also serves you as Google maps you are looking for.

Hope this helpful.!

Comment: I am from Iran. Our country has been sanctioned by the company ESRI. So I can not use the company's services

Answer (score 0):

based  on  Russell answer .

Google licensing terms generally prohibit accessing their tile service from outside of the controls they provide

but    you can  use  this class as  a layer  in you application.

```
public enum TypeOfTile
   {
    sateliteImage,
    map
   }

public static class TypeOfTileExtensions
{

    public static string TotileString(this TypeOfTile me)
    {
        switch (me)
        {
            case TypeOfTile.sateliteImage:
                return "s@92";
            case TypeOfTile.map:
                return "m@161000000";

            default:
                return "t@128";
        }
    }
}

public class GoogleTilecLayer : TiledMapServiceLayer
{
    private const double cornerCoordinate = 20037508.3427892;
    private string _baseURL;
    public GoogleTilecLayer(TypeOfTile typetile)
    {

        _baseURL = typetile.TotileString();

    }

    public override void Initialize()
    {
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Projection.WebMercator mercator = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Projection.WebMercator();
        this.FullExtent = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.Envelope(-20037508.3427892, -20037508.3427892, 20037508.3427892, 20037508.3427892)
        {
            SpatialReference = new SpatialReference(102100)
        };

        this.SpatialReference = new SpatialReference(102100);

        this.TileInfo = new TileInfo()
        {
            Height = 256,
            Width = 256,
            Origin = new MapPoint(-cornerCoordinate, cornerCoordinate) { SpatialReference = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.SpatialReference(102100) },
            Lods = new Lod[16]
        };

        double resolution = cornerCoordinate * 2 / 256;
        for (int i = 0; i < TileInfo.Lods.Length; i++)
        {
            TileInfo.Lods[i] = new Lod() { Resolution = resolution };
            resolution /= 2;
        }

        base.Initialize();
    }

    public override string GetTileUrl(int level, int row, int col)
    {

        string url = "http://mt" + (col % 4) + ".google.cn/vt/lyrs=" + _baseURL + "&v=w2.114&hl=en_US&gl=cn&" + "x=" + col + "&" + "y=" + row + "&" + "z=" + level + "&s=Galil";
        if (_baseURL == "s@92")
        {
            url = "http://mt" + (col % 4) + ".google.cn/vt/lyrs=" + _baseURL + "&v=w2.114&hl=en_US&gl=cn&" + "x=" + col + "&" + "y=" + row + "&" + "z=" + level + "&s=Galil";
        }
        if (_baseURL == "t@128")
        {
            url = "http://mt" + (col % 4) + ".google.cn/vt/lyrs=" + _baseURL + ",r@169000000&v=w2.114&hl=en_US&gl=cn&" + "x=" + col + "&" + "y=" + row + "&" + "z=" + level + "&s=Galil";
        }
        if (_baseURL == "m@161000000")
        {
            url = "http://mt" + (col % 4) + ".google.cn/vt/lyrs=" + _baseURL + "&v=w2.114&hl=en_US&gl=cn&" + "x=" + col + "&" + "y=" + row + "&" + "z=" + level + "&s=Galil";
        }


        return string.Format(url);

    }
}
```